# Navigation bar 48dp on every screen

Tags: android, html, scale, navigationbar

I'm trying to make an android app. But I'm having many troubles with the design. I want to make a navigaton bar with a height of 48 dp on every screen. I know which height in px I have to use but I don't understand which width because every screen has another and it dosen't scale right. I just want a navigaton bar in one color with a height of 48dp and a witdh which scales to the screen so that it is from the left all way to the right with a continious height of 48dp. I hope you understand my problem if not please ask. Thanks for your time!

FOR PEOPLE WITH SAME PROBLEM:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: are u using images in navigation?

Comment: ImageButtons. The Navbar is just gray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer is deprecated. Please use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`.

Comment: Yes. But as an example for hdpi I need to make a navbar with a height of 72px but which width should I take? I'm using photoshop so I also can choose which dpi the image should have. I also don't know what to choose there.

Comment: If the image does not change along the width of the image (i.e. a solid color or horizontal stripes) 1px is sufficient. It keeps the overall package size to a minimum. If it is a solid color, You can always just set the background color of the view to whatever color you like and save yourself from using bitmaps at all.

Comment: Okay so I'm going to try this: hdpi: 72px x 1px xhdpi: 96px x 1px mdpi: 48px x 1px xxhdpi: 144px x 1px. Then into the xml code android:layout_width="fill parent" and it should work.

Comment: That should work. If I were you, I would just use the 144px image and let the system resize it for you according to the size of the view. I'm not sure why this isn't the recommended thing to do, but I find it easier and that it keeps the packages smaller. If you were making an icon set or something of that nature, I wouldn't recommend it because you would be rescaling many many images, but since the system is already stretching the image, just let it stretch it in the vertical direction as well. For 1 image, you wont see any performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more attribute

```
android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
```

(Grow the horizontal size of the object if needed so it completely fills its container.)

<kbd>[FOR HELP](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)</kbd>

Comment: You can use `android:gravity` in linear layout.

Comment: Yes but I#m using relative so I cant change to linear.